# Macro compilation fails in rust. (time out)

Tags: rust

I want to create an extended `Range` crate with a start index, end index, and number of steps. So I created the following code. As a result, the compilation times out. What is the problem with this macro?

```rust
use std::ops::Range;
use std::convert::From;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyRange<Idx> {
    start: Idx,
    end: Idx,
    step: Idx
}

impl<Idx> From<Range<Idx>> for MyRange<Idx> {
    fn from(range: Range<Idx>) -> MyRange<Idx> {
        MyRange { start: range.start, end: range.end, step: 0 }
    }
}

macro_rules! range {
    ($($t:tt)*) => {
        range!(@parse $($t:tt)*)
    };

    (@parse $range:expr) => {
        MyRange::from($range)
    };
    
    (@parse $range:expr;step:expr) => {
        let mut r = MyRange::from($rage);
        r.step = $step;
        r
    }
}

fn main() {
    let range = range!(0..3);
    println!("{:?}", range);
}
```

Comment: You need to reorder the clauses in the macro - right now the first one matches and calls itself with a larger input recursively forever which is probably causing the crash.

Answer (score -2):

```rust
use std::ops::Range;
use std::convert::From;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyRange<Idx> {
    start: Idx,
    end: Idx,
    step: Idx,
}

impl<Idx> From<Range<Idx>> for MyRange<Idx> 
where
    Idx: Copy,
{
    fn from(range: Range<Idx>) -> MyRange<Idx> {
        MyRange { start: range.start, end: range.end, step: 1 }
    }
}

macro_rules! range {
    ($range:expr) => {
        MyRange::from($range)
    };

    ($range:expr, $step:expr) => {
        {
            let mut r = MyRange::from($range);
            r.step = $step;
            r
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    let range = range!(0..3, 1);
    println!("{:?}", range);
}
```